# Read large csv file into array c++

Tags: c++, csv

I am trying to read a csv file  with over 170000 rows with 10 columns each entry.
I wrote this code using c++ (in visual studio 2017) to read it, but it only reads 3600 entries before failing.

```
// Trial1.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;
int main()
{

    ifstream file("Brightest Day.csv");

    if (!file.is_open())
    {
        cout << "ERROR: File Open" << "\n";
    }

    string data[3000][10];

    for (long i = 0; i < 3000; i++)
    {

            for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
            {
                getline(file, data[i][j], ',');

            }

    }

    for (long i = 0; i < 3000; i++)
    {

        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
        {
            cout<<data[i][j]<<" | ";
            if (j == 10)
            {
                cout << "\n";
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Even if it could only read around 10000 entries, I'd call it a success

Comment: [Rubber ducky wants to know what the significance of 3000 is.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging)

Comment: [Recommended reading.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)

Comment: `if (!file.is_open())
    {
        cout << "ERROR: File Open" << "\n";
    }
` looks like botched error handling to me. If the file is not open you print an error but *continue anyway*.

Comment: *In what way does this program fail?* It's not enough to simply say "it reads 3600 before failing". Are you getting an error message? Is the program crashing? Is it failing to compile? What kind of failure is occurring?

Comment: Uhhh... `for (long i = 0; i < 3000; i++)`... `over 170000 rows` .... `i < 3000`...

Comment: With over 170000 rows you are most likely going to run out of stack space if you keep trying to store your strings there (`string data[3000][10];` - besides, that array is never going to hold 170000 strings, no matter how hard you really want it to) - use a `std::vector`.

Comment: 3000 * 10 => 30,000 strings.  On ubuntu 17.10 (64 bit), std::string occupies 32 bytes in stack (and I presume the data is in heap), so 30,000 * 32 = 960 Kbytes, < 1 M.   Ubuntu default 'stack' size is 8 M bytes.  (My machine's heap size is 3+ GBytes).    170,000 * 32 is about 5.5 MB bytes, which is a big proportion of 8M, but I think will still fit in comfortably in my Ubuntu 17.10.  The point is to estimate you memory usage.  (and use std::vector)

Comment: In your current code, add a couple of diagnostic counters ... how many file lines / strings have been read, and how many chars have been put into the string.  Display these status every so many lines (may 10, or 100, or 1000 lines).   The biggest number you see might provide some diagnostic investigation ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are overflowing your stack.  Welcome to this website.

Your call stack is designed for small objects whose sizes are known at compile time.  That's why [your rubber ducky is wondering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) where 3000 came from.  It's a guess, and anyone creating a 3001-line csv will likely crash your program.  If you think 10000 lines is a success, then 10001 lines is a crash.

Use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).  It's an array-like structure.  It manages its own size.  And it doesn't store your data on the limited stack.

Comment: Addendum: The math goes down something like this: in MSVC 32 bit, a `std::string` is 28 bytes 28 *10 = 280 bytes per row. 3600 rows is 1008000 bytes. The standard Windows stack is 1MB, so very little wiggle room is left for anything else. If compiling for 64 bit, pointers are bigger so `std::string` is bigger. You can probably only get about 2600  rows in 64 bit.